# JSP include page. Pass back the parameter to the caller

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I have a jsp file. on that jsp file i have a variable let say an integer. so i would like to call another jsp file and pass this integer variable to the file. then after the called file finish executing, i will pass back the parameter to  the caller file. example:

```
        int count = 0;
        .
        .
        .
        .
        <jsp:include page="anotherfile.jsp">
            <jsp:param name="count" value='<%=count%>'
        </jsp:include>
        .
        .
        out.println(count);
```

now, anotherfile.jsp will do its process and change the value of `count` variable. then the caller will output the count.

Note: using `<%@ include page="anotherfile.jsp" %>` to call the file is not an option now because it will cause `exceeding the 65535 bytes limit` error to occur

Please help

Comment: Maybe you can instead pass a mutable object like AtomicInteger that can be modified by the included jsp?

Comment: You can try this in a different way. In jsp1 set the value to request. request.setAttribute("count", count); and get this value in another jsp. And set the value again another jsp to get the latest value in the first jsp.

Comment: @Sudhakar using request.setAttribute method actually helps. thanks